# Google material design web top app bar icon clicking is removing vue-router link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vue-router

In this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--modal">
                <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
                    <router-link to="/" v-on:click.native="dclick">
                        <span class="mdc-list-item__graphic material-icons" aria-hidden="true">file_copy</span>
                        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">name1</span>
                    </router-link>
                    <router-link to="/bar" v-on:click.native="dclick">
                        <span class="mdc-list-item__graphic material-icons" aria-hidden="true">file_copy</span>
                        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">name2</span>
                    </router-link>
                </div>
            </aside>
            <div class="mdc-drawer-scrim"></div>
            <div class="mdc-drawer-app-content">
                <div>
                    <header class="mdc-top-app-bar mdc-top-app-bar--fixed">
                        <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
                            <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
                                <a href="#" class="demo-menu material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">file_copy</a>
                                <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Title</span>
                            </section>

                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="mdc-top-app-bar--fixed-adjust">
                        <router-view></router-view>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            body {
                margin:0;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            Vue.component('A', {
                template : "<div>A</div>"
            });
            Vue.component('B', {
                template : "<div>B</div>"
            });
            var vm = new Vue({
                el: "#app",
                router : new VueRouter({
                    routes : [
                        { path: '/', component: Vue.component("A")},
                        { path: '/bar', component: Vue.component("B")}
                    ]
                }),
                data : {},
                mounted : function() {
                    this.drawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer'))
                    var drawer = this.drawer;

                    var topAppBar = mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(document.querySelector(".mdc-top-app-bar"));
                    topAppBar.setScrollTarget(document.querySelector(".mdc-top-app-bar").parentNode);
                    topAppBar.listen('MDCTopAppBar:nav', function (event) {
                        drawer.open = !drawer.open;
                    });
                },
                methods : {
                    dclick : function() {
                        this.drawer.open = !this.drawer.open;
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using Google material design (web) topAppBar and Drawer, plus vue/vue-router. I want to change views when clicking links in the drawer.

What I find is that when you open the drawer and click `name2` so the link changes to `/#/bar`, then click the topappbar icon to open the drawer, the link goes away, it just becomes `/`.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, establish a charset on your html, cause this will probably give you bigger trouble especially, when you escalate it, then, mind in your B component (Ln 33):

```
<section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
    <a href="#" class="demo-menu material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">file_copy</a>
    <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Title</span>
</section>
```

I just stripped 'href="#"' out and everything comes to normal. I really don't know if you're using material.io with VueJS the right way and/or if there's one. There are material frameworks more Vue-friendly. Remember that if you're using third party 'techs' to manipulate the DOM outside of Vue scope there will be trouble.